# Does the nth char equal the nth from last char?

Tags: code-golf, string

Inspired by [Does the start equal the end](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120434/does-the-start-equal-the-end)

Given a string `s` and an integer `n`, output a truthy/falsey as to whether the `n`th char in `s` equals the `n`th from the end char in `s`.

## Input

A non-empty string and an integer. You can use 0-based indexing or 1-based indexing. The integer is guaranteed to be valid based on the string. For example, if the string is "supercalifragalistic123", the integer can be from 1 to 23 for 1-based indexing, and 0 to 22 for 0-based indexing. Please note that `n` can be larger than half the length of `s`.

Input is limited to printable ASCII.

## Output

A truthy/falsey value based on whether the `n`th value in `s` equals the `n`th from last value in `s`.

Please note that the last char is in position 0 for 0-based indexing and position 1 for 1-based indexing. Think of it as comparing the string to its reverse.

## Test Cases

0-indexed

```
"1", 0         Truthy 1 == 1
"abc", 1       Truthy b == b
"aaaaaaa", 3   Truthy a == a
"[][]", 1      Falsey ] != [
"[][]", 0      Falsey [ != ]
"ppqqpq", 2    Truthy q == q
"ababab", 5    Falsey a != b
"12345", 0     Falsey 1 != 5
"letter", 1    Truthy e == e
"zxywv", 3     Falsey w != x
```

1-indexed

```
"1", 1         Truthy 1 == 1
"abc", 2       Truthy b == b
"aaaaaaa", 4   Truthy a == a
"[][]", 2      Falsey ] != [
"[][]", 1      Falsey [ != ]
"ppqqpq", 3    Truthy q == q
"ababab", 6    Falsey a != b
"12345", 1     Falsey 1 != 5
"letter", 2    Truthy e == e
"zxywv", 4     Falsey w != x
```

Comment: [Sandbox (deleted)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12672/65836)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to take `n` as a code-point? (for esoteric languages such as brain-flak)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s>  4 bytes

```
=UƓị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@28bemzyw93d//8b/1cqKCgsLChUAgA)

There should be no shorter answers in Jelly. An program would need comparison, reversal/negation, an index call, and a byte for control flow (`Ɠ` in this case), which adds up to four bytes.

**How it works**

```
 =UƓị 
       - (implicit) input string
 =     - equals (vectorizing by characters because a string is a charlist)
  U    - the reversed string
    ị  - get the element at the index of:
   Ɠ   - the input index
```

*-1 byte thanks to @ais523, using `Ɠ`*

Comment: Failed 4 byte solution from original version of post: `ịµU=`

Comment: You can improve it to four bytes by making it monadic rather than dyadic (and taking *n* from standard input rather than an argument): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@28bemzyw93d//8b/1cqKCgsLChUAgA "Jelly – TIO Nexus") This technique is often useful when you're wasting a byte on control flow and an additional byte on `³`, as the `Ɠ` costs one byte but makes the `³` implicit and often gives you more control flow flexibility.

Comment: @ais512 Good idea, I have actually never used the input before in an answer because implicit arguments tend to be more efficient.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

```
s=>n=>s[n]==s.substr(~n,1)
```

Alternatively:

```
s=>n=>s[n]==s.slice(~n)[0]
```

This one almost works, but fails when `n == 0` (because `s.slice(-1,0) == ""`):

```
s=>n=>s[n]==s.slice(~n,-n)
```

Another 26-byte solution that [@RickHitchcock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42260/rick-hitchcock) pointed out:

```
s=>n=>s[n]==s[s.length+~n]
```

Comment: Nice use of `~`, would never have though of that for this.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
tP=w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@18SYFuu@f@/ukdqTmq@OpcRAA)

Explanation:

```
t   % Duplicate the input

Stack:
    ['ppqqpq' 'ppqqpq']

P   % Reverse the top element of the stack

Stack:
    ['ppqqpq' 'qpqqpp']

=   % Equals. Push an array of the indices that are equal

Stack:
    [[0 1 1 1 1 0]]

w   % Swap the top two elements

Stack:
    [[0 1 1 1 1 0], 3]

)   % Grab the a'th element of b
```

Comment: Very clever approach!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thankyou! That is quiet the complement coming from you :)

Comment: Now we see if Jelly can beat this xD

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Adnan.*

```python
lambda s,n:s[n]==s[~n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQrJNnVRydF2trWxxdlxf7v6AoM69EIU1D3VBdR8FAkwvOT0xKBooYIotAAFDUGEk0OjY6Fk0hVAjZtIKCwsKCQqCgEYoVIAgUNEUSNDQyNjFF052TWlKSWoRmS1VFZXkZ2DH/AQ)

Comment: I think you can replace `-n-1` by `~n`.

Comment: Why only Python2? Seems to work on Python3 just fine, you should change it to just 'Python'.

Comment: @sagiksp it's the default template output in TIO

Comment: Oh, makes sense.

Comment: @sagiksp Yeah, it's the template from TIO but updated. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 22 bytes

```matlab
@(s,n)s(n)==s(end-n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/LDoIwEAXQvV8xkpjQiCTl4a6JK7/AXdNFwRIXplJAHv587QAKYbrsyb0zr7yRrbIFC8PQXvw60KT2NWGs9pW@n/SRElv4HvUCoASmOQDcqnfzGIACY0B3DsgsdyQiG5AhyEYwjUMJWQGJQCLggot/hANX@azVAAL2DPgK0A3gCASCsjSmNI7EBMHcYLDBTDvic/9nsg6QGDDuSKM4SX8VC6AIUgRP1TSqmrdcjlBYoRB8@qFrpxvXCR0m9PYL)

Or the same bytecount:

```matlab
@(s,n)s(n)==flip(s)(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/LCoMwEAXQfb9iKhQMiBAf3QW66hd0J1lEibQgbWKsj/68zRhbg8kmkMO9M6@qE72caxbH8XwJTfQkJnwSxurmoUJD7Huuw4AGEVAC7pwAbu27u09AgTGgBwtEWVmSkB0oEZQLcMeijHhAIBAICl7wf4QFV9EYOQGHI4PCA3QHCgQcgVJaK21JShCsDRobtJsRr/0/Ez9AYMAyI03SLP9VbIAiyBE0sutku065LSGxQiL4jNPQux39hAETxvkL)

**Explanation:**

It's quite straight forward. The first one takes a string `s` and an integer `n` as inputs and checks the n'th element `s(n)` against the "last-n+1" element for equality.

The second one checks the n'th element `s(n)` against the n'th element of `s` reversed.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

```
ÂøsèË
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@46fCO4sMrDnf//19QUFhYUMhlBAA) or [Try all tests](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#K6tMKP5/uOnwjuLDKw53/69UOrzfSsklvdje0KxY1@3wBvtanf/R0eqG6joGsTrR6olJyeo6hmAWBKjrGIN40bHRsVAJCBOsuqCgsLCgUF3HCKIVBNV1TEEcQyNjE1OoqpzUkpLUIqjuqorK8jKQobEA)

```
Â     # Add a reversed copy on top of the original string
 ø    # Zip
  sè  # Extract the nth element
    Ë # Check if they are equal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@46fCO4sMrDnf//19QUFhYUMhlBAA)

Comment: `ÂøsèË` saves two bytes

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! I knew there was a 1 byte way to add a reversed copy, I just couldn't remember how it was labeled.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony I forgot to update it to include Adnan's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 22 bytes

```
s#n=s!!n==reverse s!!n
```

0-basd. Usage example: `"letter" # 1` -> `True`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1g5z7ZYUTHP1rYotSy1qDhVAcT7n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCioJSTWlKSWqSkoKxg@B8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 24 bytes

```
/t.~e?/-mom
\I!RtI&1n;@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1@/RK8u1V5fNzc/lyvGUzGoxFPNMM/aQf///4KCwsKCQi5jAA)

Input consists of the string on one line, and the number on the second line.  Output is `Jabberwocky` if the characters are the same, and nothing otherwise.

#### Explanation

This program is mostly in ordinal mode, with one command in cardinal mode.  Linearized, the program is as follows:

```
I.ReI&1m;mt!~t?&-no

I  % Input first line
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq"]
.  % Duplicate top of stack
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "ppqqpq"]
R  % Reverse top of stack
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpqqpp"]
e  % Push empty string
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpqqpp", ""]
I  % Input next line
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpqqpp", "", "3"]
&  % (cardinal mode) Pop stack and repeat next command that many times
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpqqpp", ""], ITERATOR: [3]
1  % Append "1" to top of stack
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpqqpp", "111"]
m  % Truncate so the top two strings on the stack have the same length
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpq", "111"]
;  % Discard top of stack
   % STACK: ["ppqqpq", "qpq"]
m  % Truncate again
   % STACK: ["ppq", "qpq"]
t  % Extract last character
   % STACK: ["ppq", "qp", "q"]
!  % Move top of stack to tape
   % STACK: ["ppq", "qp"]
~  % Swap
   % STACK: ["qp", "ppq"]
t  % Extract last character
   % STACK: ["qp", "pp", "q"]
?  % Copy data from tape onto top of stack
   % STACK: ["qp', "pp", "q", "q"]
&  % Iterator: effectively a no-op in ordinal mode when the top of the stack is a 1-character string
   % STACK: ["qp", "pp", "q"], ITERATOR: ["q"]
-  % Remove occurrences: here, result is "" iff the characters are equal
   % STACK: ["qp", "pp", ""]
n  % Logical Not (for a consistent truthy value)
   % STACK: ["qp", "pp", "Jabberwocky"]
o  % Output top of stack
```

Comment: @MartinEnder Jabberwocky?

Comment: @StephenS [Jabberwocky.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky)

Comment: @StephenS Btw, I don't get notifications if you just mention me on random posts. Pings only work if the post is mine or I've commented myself (and I think if I edited the post). You're usually better off pinging me in chat.

Comment: @MartinEnder I kind of knew that, but it wasn't important enough to ping you. Thanks for the confirmation and the link :)

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>26, 16</s>, 13 bytes

```
ä$Àñã2xñVpøˆ±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///ASlcMNhzceXmxUcXhjWMHhHYc6Dm38/z8xCQT/mwEA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e424 c0f1 e332 78f1 5670 f888 b1         .$...2x.Vp...
```

1 indexed.

Explanation:

```
ä$                  " Duplicate this line horizontally
  Àñ   ñ            " Arg1 times...
    ã               "   Move to the center of this line
     2x             "   And delete two characters
        V           " Select this whole line
         p          " And replace it with the last pair of characters we deleted
          ø         " Count the number of matches of the following regex...
           <0x88>   "   Any character
                 ±  "   Followed by itself
```

For reference, my original answer was:

```
Àñx$x|ñxv$hhpÓ¨.©±/1
ñllS0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3@44fDGCpWKGiBZppKRUXB48qEVeodWHtqob8h1eGNOTrDB//8eqTmp@f8NAQ) (0 indexed)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c0f1 7824 787c f178 7624 6868 70d3 a82e  ..x$x|.xv$hhp...
00000010: a9b1 2f31 0af1 6c6c 5330                 ../1..llS0
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/92///DgMOxfHgkeMOxw6Rsw4dewqguwqkuKsKxJC9k//9IZWxhSP8w "V – Try It Online")  This is a bit shorter.  Man the `Àñx$x|ñ` feels like too many characters.  I tried a regex only, but it ended up being like 24 long!

Comment: @nmjcman101 Turns out it can be much shorter than that using newer features.

Comment: Oh wow I'm out of practice, I can barely even read V anymore

Comment: @nmjcman101 I've posted an explanation (and golfed a little more)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
s->n->s.charAt(n)==s.charAt(s.length()+~n)
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZA9T8MwEIb3/IpTp1g0FmnpFBIJBiQGpo5RBtc1qYNjO/ElEFD56yFVQxAspD4P9/XovbuCtSwwVuhi/9LL0poaoRhytEGp6HOjOUqj6cPoRB5XzDl4@vAAHDKUHL5rt1uspc6XP4lHjSIX9RLujVGC6SQBDjH0Lkh0kDjKD6y@Q1@TOJ4CR5XQOR58cvWpSR8NOsO3zU4NUqNia@QeSia1f5ZMM2DkNBHAtnMoSmoapHYoodI@p8xa1fmLcEFG95qQ6N92tuMTEM4Czm@C1nOgNEuzy2R@EbM2sbaqbDUxq3nbn2xiNnOYcLW@2Vw2mhKIor7sAO9v3Wv798pH79h/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 22 bytes

```
..@.IAp):tBvpptc?1.\O0
```

1-indexed, takes input as `index`,`string`, separated by a space.

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li5ALklBcCk6dEJ2cHB0Yz8xLlxPMA==&input=MiBsZXR0ZXI=&speed=5)

Cubified

```
    . .
    @ .
I A p ) : t B v
p p t c ? 1 . \
    O 0
    . .
```

#### Explanation

This is mostly linear.  The main logic is

```
IAp):tBpptc

IA           Get the first input as an int and the rest as a string.
  p):        Move the index to the top of the stack, increment it, and copy it.
     t       Look up the appropriate character in the string.
      Bpp    Reverse the stack and put the index and character back on top.
         t   Look up the appropriate character in the reversed string.
          c  XOR the two characters.
```

We then branch with `?` to `O`utput `1` if the result is 0 and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```c#
s=>n=>s[n]==s[s.Length+~n];
```

*Saved a byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen.*

Compiles to a `Func<string, Func<int, bool>>`.

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `s.Length-n-1` to `s.Length+~n`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, nice trick never would have thought of that.

Comment: I will be completely honest, I got it from the comment of the JS answer myself. :) Byte-operations aren't really my expertise.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>22</s>  <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
->s,n{s[n]==s[~n]}
```

Comment: I guess `->s,n{s[n]==s[~n]}` should work? (Got no idea of ruby)

Comment: It does, nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
l~_W%.==
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P6cuPlxVz9b2/39DBaWc1JKS1CIlAA)

0-indexed index goes first.

Answer (score 3):

### R 51 bytes

```
function(s,n){s=el(strsplit(s,''));s[n]==rev(s)[n]}
```

Anonymous function, uses 1-based indexing

Comment: 43 bytes: `function(s,n)(s=utf8ToInt(s))[n]==rev(s)[n]`

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, 27 bytes

```
#(nth(map =(reverse %)%)%2)
```

Wow, this was shorter than I expected.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>10</s> 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/74163)

```
⊃=⊃∘⌽
```

This is a tacit function, which needs to be assigned a name such as `f←⊃=⊃∘⌽`, and then called as `int f string`.

Thanks to @Adám for a whopping 5 bytes.

#### How it works:

```
⊃=⊃∘⌽  ⍝ Main function; tacit. 
       ⍝ Inputs are ⍺ = 1 (left) and ⍵ = 'abca' (right).
⊃      ⍝ ⍺⊃⍵, meaning 'pick the ⍺-th element of ⍵'
 =     ⍝ Compare to
    ⌽  ⍝ ⌽⍵, meaning 'invert ⍵'
  ⊃    ⍝ Again, ⍺⊃⍵, but:
   ∘   ⍝ Compose. This turns ⌽ into the right argument for ⊃,
       ⍝ which becomes 'pick the ⍺-th element from ⌽(the inverse of)⍵'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBGmP2iY86mq2BeJHHTMe9ezlMlFIU1DPSS0pSS1SBwA)

The 22 byte answer was edited out. If you want to see it, check the revision history.

Comment: " it takes the input in a non conventional way" -- taking 2 element input as the left and right args in APL is completely standard and always acceptable unless the OP specifically forbids it for some bizarre reason.

Comment: @Jonah yeah, people in chat enlightened me about that. I left it as is because OP doesn't specify clearly if it's okay or not. I'll edit that when I get back to my PC so the shorter answer appears first.

Comment: Regarding "implicitly assumes": Actually, this function will work even when called monadically, and will then appear to use `1` as default left argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBGmP2iY86mq2BeJHHTMe9ezlSlNQz0ktKUktUgcx04HMzLx0dQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") The functions don't assume anything; they are being applied dyadically because they are given both a left and a right argument.

Comment: @Adám I thought that happened because, when called monadically, `⊃` takes the first element of the argument? Anyway, I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
{]=|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6tjbWv0/mtyKekpqKfZWqkr6CjUWimkFXNxpSZn5CsYKtgCcZqCemJSsjpCyBgkVFBQWFhQqA5VaQBTGR0bHauOJmZoZGxiqv4fAA)

*-4 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog for `{(=|.)`*

See original answer explanation -- idea is similar enough, but this is accomplished with a dyadic hook whose right verb is itself a monadic hook.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6s1bGv0NP9rcinpKain2VqpK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrGCrYAnGagnpiUrI6QsgYJFRQUFhYUKgOVWkAUxkdGx2rjiZmaGRsYqr@HwA)

#### original answer (10 bytes)

```
{=/@(,:|.)
```

`,:|.` right arg on top of reverse right arg

`=/` are they elementwise equal?

`{` take from that boolean list the index indicated by the left arg

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6tt9R00dKxq9DT/a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkKxgq2AJxmoJ6YlKyOkLIGCRUUFBYWFCoDlVpAFMZHRsdq44mZmhkbGKq/h8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 20 bytes

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [TheLethalCoder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123932/110384), but in C# 8 you can save some more bytes.

```cs
s=>n=>s[n]==s[^++n];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY89D4IwEIZ3f0XDRAMaAZmwXUyc3B2amkhTTBNyBVo//3ytymh7N12eJ3fvCbMURrn9FcTW2EnBJUffQYHNUat1TynqEHGGUCDUMOCEGHbKMuCN22kwuper46SsPCiQaZcmRYLTNcbN4i89t8LzIsx/5Z0q6DDOeHTJLIRTDMM4DqNXykjQT3ulDipFWW3q6J1eWiunaNbX43m/ze@6Nw)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 46 bytes

```
function f(s,n)return s:byte(n)==s:byte(-n)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7NCoMwDAfwu09RPLWgBz@2w8CrT7CbeKguMkGyfqTb3Mt3HQpzsuQSfoT8Mznp/eCwp/GGbOA2QWGAnEFmT91MwFFU1TqmKAAvPk3Z2Ti6zozAEuulBRspMyLxgcdZnLBMiC/Irg@U/9BSgcstK6W10kGLrU5ABGY9EYXwWk4W/oc3bdPuw1bb/fTpoMetZnlRHvarr@f8uC@f@jc)

Comment: you can't assume the input is already in `s`, and you need to output it as well

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 34 Bytes

```
s=StringTake;s[#,{#2}]==s[#,{-#2}]&
```

Comment: `StringTake[#, #2]` takes the **first** `#2` characters of `#`. `StringPart` would work well in this case. `#~(s=StringPart)~-#2==s@##&`

Comment: my wrong. fixed!

Comment: `#~s~{#2}==#~s~{#2}&` would always yield `True`...

Comment: final fixed!....

Comment: That fixes it, but `StringPart` does not require a `List`: `#~(s=StringPart)~-#2==s@##&` or `s=StringPart;s@##==#~s~-#2&` works too.

Comment: Actually, you can take a `List` of `String`s as input, so `#[[#2]]==#[[-#2]]&` would suffice

Comment: very nice. I didn't know about it

Comment: Note that this is not a function. `&` (`Function`) have higher priority than `;` (`CompoundExpression`), so that is interpreted as `CompoundExpression[s=StringTake,s[#,{#2}]==s[#,{-#2}]&]`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP>=7.1, 36 Bytes

```php
[,$t,$p]=$argv;echo$t[$p]==$t[~+$p];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bed3d1ef5870c0d0d552b4fc84367a13df071303)

Comment: `~+$p` saves one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 27 bytes

```perl6
{[eq] $^a.comb[$^b,*-1-$b]}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#VZBbcoIwGIXfs4q/Gab1EhnR2gcR7VNX4BtgJ0BsnQG5BFTq6GLadbgml2ATwKhhhjD5zjk5PwVnsHnTfRNFJTz7ccDAuuxtlrqgLajux5FnawuPdHpGT/Pcw0XI3nPGc7AgXK0Zb7X1iCbjPQKIxlxuAOfTLz6f/uCovrQJz7PV@msqbHpnVqleyEu1a5N4ueQsl8wJutWZrU0yxouwOpxnRf5dutJ1MMXrqNIIdJWbwEyZCGifJjqgQkw3F2VNlIR0Dd2quYmWcdYM0ZtCy6nDiFMHEYftEubnLCBOwLjfBjnUioP8Oa1GW0vbBJQWpFbcecEGJtCH66rLgwGWBQbC1PMFNh6hJ6EnYL2EYHiDVEKKsO3a7s36QUPOSnDhyQJbwf4DtCV0EU6SNE1SgQd3d6YyNpWF5CPg6M5JpVMUMgbD15HKbaAh4QjhkOU5y66VmlgmYxnCP7tyu2kGUc6tdO7@AQ)

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with two placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

  [eq]        # reduce using string equality operator

    $^a       # declare first positional parameter

    .comb\    # split that into individual characters

    [         # index into that sequence

      $^b,    # declare and use second parameter

      *-1-$b  # closure that subtracts one and the 
              # second parameter of the outer block
              # (｢*｣ is the parameter of this closure)

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
q@zQ@_z
```

With the input reversed: first the index, then the string. It is 0-indexed.

## Explanations:

```
q@zQ@_z
 @zQ        Get the nth (Qth) character
     _z     Reverse the string
    @       Get the nth character of the reversed string. Implicit input of the index
q           Test equality
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q%40zQ%40_z&input=2%0Appqqpq&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
#define f(s,n)s[n]==s[strlen(s)+~n]
```

Uses 0-based indexing, naturally.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU2jWCdPszg6L9bWtji6uKQoJzVPo1hT11A3L/Z/bmJmnoYmVzWXAhAUFGXmlaRpKKmmxOQp6QAZ4fk5hvnhSjqGmprW@FUYgVTU/gcA)

Comment: I think `-1-n` can be `+~n`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 24 bytes

```
[ 2dup nth -rot nth* = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjUJxaWJqal5xajGDppVaUFCUWKxQUpZaUVBYUZeaVKFhzcRkqKEXHRscq/Y9WMEopLVDIK8lQ0C3KLwExtBRsFWL/Jyfm5Cjo/QcA)

### Explanation

`nth*` is like `nth` except it indexes from the back; if `0 nth` is the first element, `0 nth*` is the last.

```
             ! 1 "[][]"
2dup         ! 1 "[][]" 1 "[][]"
nth          ! 1 "[][]" 93
-rot         ! 93 1 "[][]"
nth*         ! 93 91
=            ! f
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
Drz.=sAI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrXIqq9GyLHT0hXKjoghUFBYWFBYVcRhA-AA)

0-indexed. Change `AI` to `AH` if you want it to be 1-indexed.

##### Explanation

```python
Drz.=sAI  # Implicit input
Dr        # Duplicate and reverse
  z.=     # Zipped equality
     sAI  # Swap and index in
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
fḂ=i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJm4biCPWkiLCIiLCJwcHFxcHFcbjIiXQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
fḂ=i  # Implicit input
f     # Flatten into a list of characters
 Ḃ    # Bifurcate: duplicate and reverse
  =   # Are they equal (vectorises)
   i  # Index in
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### ZSH, 32

```
f(){read s n;[ $s[n] = $s[-n] ]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYqxDoIwAET3fsWFEKKDiQV0oY5uDsbNNB0QSiAhpQUiivjttZW74S53bx5qW222n17mJQaojCMcuBI4@dy5Ir52qptWwiMZyg6MsSC8na@Xe4AFFaIIsqg7UCzL2vaeU9JaCkryR4GY5KuQEi64cMM/KNHaGG2QOMwbR0LjJD24p5XjKHtHzq/39ET6Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10 9</s> 8 bytes

```
gV ¥Ug~V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@58epnBoaWh6Xdj//0qJScmJSjoKRgA)

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
?_s;,:,1|=_sA,-a,1
```

Explanation

```
?        =     PRINT -1 if equal, 0 otherwise, between
 _s     |      A substring of
   ;,:,1          A$ string (read from cmd line), from the n'th pos, length 1
 _sA,-a,1      And a substring of A$, n'th pos from the right, also 1 length
               The second Substring is auto-terminated because EOF.
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
q~_2$=@@~==
```

Bad. Too much stack manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 57 Bytes

Assuming header includes don't count.

```
bool c(std::string s,int i){return s[i]==s[s.size()-i];}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can remove the spaces at `int i){` and `s[i]==s[` to make it 54 bytes.

Comment: I don't think this is valid. The first parameter needs to be given an identifier, otherwise you cannot refer to it. But you *don't* need the space between the closing parenthesis of the function signature and the opening brace of its definition, so this would only increase your code size by 1 byte. You'd get a net decrease by removing the spaces around the equals sign, as Kevin suggested.

Comment: In addition to removing spaces and including `s` in the parameter list you could also replace `bool` by `int`.

Comment: `#include<string> int c(std::string s,int i){return s[i]==s[s.size()-i];}`(line break of course) is the smallest I get to compile. If you find a compiler that includes `<string>` on default you may drop it.

Comment: shouldn't it be `s[s.size()-i-1]` or at least `s[s.size()+~i]`?

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) (with [this](https://fishlanguage.com/playground) interpreter), 25 bytes

```
i:0(?v
]&=n;>~{:}[:}]&r[}
```

It doesn't work in TIO: the TIO interpreter doesn't reverse the new stack when doing the `[` instruction, but the fish playground does — compare `"abcde"5[ooooo;` run [here](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XykxKTklVck0Oh8ErP//BwA) and [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground), for example.

The string input is taken from STDIN, and we assume *n* is already on the stack. Uses 1-indexing.

The fish gets the *n*th character with `[:}]&`, which siphons off the first *n* things on the stack into a new, reversed stack, manipulates that a bit, then puts the things back and saves the *n*th character in the register. It then reverses the whole stack and does the same again, and returns 1 if the two characters are equal, and 0 otherwise.

This [seems to work at TIO](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9PKQMO@jCtWzTbP2q6u2qo2Gohj1Yqiq///d8opTU3LzFMoKc1L/K9bpmBo8DUvXzc5MTkjFQA), for 26 bytes:

```
i:0(?v
]&=n;>~{:}[{:}]&r[{
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), <strike>26</strike> 24 Bytes

```ruby
def c(s,n)s[n]==s[~n]end
```

-2 Bytes from  Felipe Nardi Batista, thanks.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/PyU1TSFZo1gnT7M4Oi/W1rY4ui4vNjUv5X9BUWZeiUayhlJiUrKSjoKhpuZ/AA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! A nice solution, to improve your answer I would recommend adding a ["Try it online"](https://tio.run/) link that shows an implementation of your answer.

Comment: `s[n]==s[~n]` saves 2 bytes

Comment: @Notts90, i don't think there are any online crystal-interpreters. :(
The homepage provides one, but I don't think it has an API?

Comment: @Domii look at the try it online link in my previous comment, it's lists crystal as one of the languages it supports.

Comment: @Notts90 Oh sry. I missed that link because the color is almost the same as the rest. Thanks :D

Comment: @Domii no worries, when you have created your code in there click the link button at the top and it even has an option that's formatted for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 73 bytes

Compiles as-is with GCC 6.3.1 (no flags). Some unnecessary obfuscation included.

```
main(c,v)char**v;{c=atoi(v[2]);putchar((*++v)[c]-(*v)[strlen(*v+1)-c]);}
```

Usage

```
$./a.out abcdcba 6
```

Truthy = nothing, falsey = garbage.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 35 bytes

Uses 1-indexing.

```lua
s,n=...print(s:byte(n)==s:byte(-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/WCfPVk9Pr6AoM69Eo9gqqbIkVSNP09YWytTN09T8//9/YlLyfyMA)

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 41 bytes

```
parse arg n,=(n)l+1''-(n)r+1 .
return l=r
```

Arguments are given in `n,s` order since `n` is required for parsing `s`.

Answer (score 1):

## shortC, 23 bytes

```
Df(s,n)s[n]==s[Ss)-1-n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fJU2jWCdPszg6L9bWtjg6uFhT11A3L/Z/bmJmnoYmVzWXAhAUFGXmlaRpKKmmxOQp6QAZ4fk5hvnhSjqGmprW@FUYgVTU/gcA)

Substitutions in this program:

- `D` -> `#define`
- `S` -> `strlen(`
- No auto-inserted closing stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 3 (`-lF`) = 26 bytes

```perl
say$F[$n=<>]eq$F[-1-$n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLFLVolz9bGLja1EMjUNdRVyYv9/z8kI7NYAYgSFYpLijLz0rmM/uUXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivm@MGAA)

Uses 0 indexing

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḳ=i
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPWQmY29kZT0lRTElQjglQjIlM0RpJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTIyMSUyMiUyQyUyMDAlMEElMjJhYmMlMjIlMkMlMjAxJTBBJTIyYWFhYWFhYSUyMiUyQyUyMDMlMEElMjIlNUIlNUQlNUIlNUQlMjIlMkMlMjAxJTBBJTIyJTVCJTVEJTVCJTVEJTIyJTJDJTIwMCUwQSUyMnBwcXFwcSUyMiUyQyUyMDIlMEElMjJhYmFiYWIlMjIlMkMlMjA1JTBBJTIyMTIzNDUlMjIlMkMlMjAwJTBBJTIybGV0dGVyJTIyJTJDJTIwMSUwQSUyMnp4eXd2JTIyJTJDJTIwMyZmbGFncz1W)

##### Explanation

```python
Ḳ=i  # Implicit input
Ḳ    # Bifurcate the input string
 =   # Check for equality (vectorised)
  i  # Index into this list
     # Implicit output
```

Comment: clever! thank you for styling the Try Thunno page better lol. and no i didn’t entirely forget about the docs site, i’ll get that done soonTM

Comment: That's ok. (Also, the restyling was mainly lyxal telling me what code to put where lol :p)

Answer (score 1):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 6 bytes

`ä¡Y=à@`

0-indexed

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=5KFZPeBA&in=InBwcXFwcSIgMg==)

### Explanation

```
ä       ; duplicate the first (implicit) input
 ¡      ; reverse it
  Y=    ; zip the two lists with equality
    à@  ; get the element at the index given by the second index
        ; implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 20 bytes

```
s=>n=>s[n]==s.at(~n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 18 bytes

```powershell
$a[$b]-eq$a[-$b-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkliUXlyjWq2SqKOSZKsSH20QqwMkDWOBMtEqSbG6qYVAhq5Kki5QqPb/fw0lQyUdBQNNBQ2lxKRkINMQzIQAINcYxI2OjY6FSSGzCwoKCwsKgTwjiH4QBPJMQTxDI2MTU5jROaklJalFMG1VFZXlZWCzAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊡:=⇌.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4oqhOj3ih4wuCgpmICJhYmNiYSIgMQpmICJhYmNkZSIgMQo=)

```
⊡:=⇌.
    .  # duplicate
   ⇌   # reverse
  =    # elementwise equal
 :     # flip
⊡      # pick
```